# Sync only a single group of tabs in firefox

Tags: firefox, browser-tabs

I usually have multiple groups of different tabs open up in firefox. When I am working on a project across multiple computers I would like to be able to sync only a single group of tabs which are relevant to my project, and not personal tabs that I have open at home. Is there a way to do this with firefox?

Answer (score 0):

Until Firefox Sync handles tab groups (that's not the case in v29), maybe you can try https://chrometabcloud.appspot.com